# Adding elements to more tags(=> add only first element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, appendchild

```js
function $(selector) {

    var resultObject = {
        append: function (element) {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var dos = parser.parseFromString(element, "text/html");

            var all = dos.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
       

            var elemWhichAppend = document.getElementsByClassName("testing");

            var children = all.childNodes;


            for (var i = 0; i < elemWhichAppend.length; i++) {
                
                var msgContainer = document.createDocumentFragment();
                var children = all.childNodes;

                for (var child = 0; child < children.length; child++) {
                
                    var al = myLo(children[child]);
                    msgContainer.appendChild(al);
                }
                insertAfter(msgContainer, elemWhichAppend[i]);
            }
            



        }
    }
    return resultObject;
}

function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}

function myLo(curElem)
{

    var whichnodetype;

    if (curElem.nodeType == 3)
    {
        whichnodetype = document.createTextNode(curElem.nodeValue);
    }
    else
    {
        var whichnodetype = document.createElement(curElem.nodeName);
    }

    var children = curElem.childNodes;
    for (var child = 0; child < children.length; child++) {
        whichnodetype.appendChild(children[child]);
    }

    return whichnodetype;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="testing">APPEND</h1>
    <p>Hallo, ich bin ein P TAG </p>
    <h2 class="testing">APPEND2</h2>
    <input type="button" value="append tag/text " onclick="$('.testing').append('<ul><li>RIBA RIBI<ul><li>FRANK RIBERY</li></ul></li></ul> <h1>NIGOGOG</h1> messi ist scheiße');" />
</body>
</html>
```

I managed to add every element to the first tag, but at the second time it only adds the last tag. See code snipped. It goes two times each loop which is correct but it still adds not correct the second time.

Comment: If you use jQuery at all, please use it. Your code will shrink to 30% or less and be much easier to understand :) Also, do not use inline click handlers with jQuery. Just use a delegated handler attached to a non-changing ancestor element.

Comment: After 5 minutes study I am more confused than ever. You seem to be duplicating basic jQuery functionality with raw javascript. Can you instead explain what the overall aim is, because I am pretty sure you can do it all in a few lines of jQuery :)

Comment: @GoneCoding My aim is to pass a tag/text (element) to my append function. This tags I want to append to my selector(class, id or elements)

Comment: That is not an aim, that is a functional description. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve as your approach appears completely redundant in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite puzzled by how you have gone about this, and why you have replaced `append` with your own version, but as an example of how to append to multiple targets using jQuery in a fraction of the code:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ad2qf4uy/

```
$('.addbutton').click(function(){
    $('.testing').append('<ul><li>RIBA RIBI<ul><li>FRANK RIBERY</li></ul></li></ul> <h1>NIGOGOG</h1> messi ist scheiße');
});
```

*If you could please explain what your aim was, that would make life so much easier :)*